# Detecting collisions in Unity3d not using OnTriggerEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

Basically my problem is the following: When the player gets a line, I have to simulate the future movement of the player to detect if it will collide with some "threat". To do that I make a clone of the player and of the threats in his/hers way. For instance, if the player are on a road with four lanes, I need to know if he/she will collide with a threat which is in his/hers current lane. I need a kind of line from the player ship and check if that line will collide with some threat. It's not possible use the triggers because I make that simulation in only one frame.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement Ray Casting is the solution. Ray Casting is forming a line or vector from a specific point to another point in a 3D plane. The purpose of the ray (vector) is to determine if it intersects with any colliders or other game objects.

It can be simply used like,

```
void Update() {
    Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    // parameters are origin, direction and length of the ray. 
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 10)){ 
        print("There is something in front of the object!");
    }
}
```

You can find more references and tutorials on the internet. Try Unity official tutorial on [Raycasting](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/raycasting)

Comment: you'll probably want to look into the "layers" aspect of raycasting too, since you'll have "real" and "temp clone" version of your gameobjects  http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html might be a good start for that.

Comment: Sure it will be useful!